# Will MySQL Work when i shutdown my computer

Tags: mysql

The question is about my PC-**Personal Computer**,
and not on the storage box, like server computer(like in my school)

So this is a simple doubt that *will `MySQL` work when I*

- Shutdown my PC
- Restart my PC
- Powercut/other stuffs

for

- Web
- Android
- ...
  Platforms

Comment: No matter the software, nothing runs on a computer that is turned off. Nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. everything including mysql background service will be killed once you turnoff your pc, and talking about your school servers, they too can't be running when they are shut down.

Comment: that answer was enough ,so i can make my blogging website only when I grow up

Comment: try firebase cloudstore and host your website on netlify.

Comment: Yes i do know firebase,the reason i thought to switch is itself because they have more limitations. anyway thanks

Comment: thats right, it is no sql database but blogging should do it fine i guess, anyway, just wanted to say dont stop trying and learning :)